# Tabela montada atraves de input select

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax

Meu problema aqui é que eu monto uma tabela através de um array recebido por Ajax,tenho 2 problemas:

1º **Toda vez que eu selecione um item no select a Tabela deveria zerar e pegar os novos dados,do jeito que eu fiz ele não ta adicionando sem deletar**

2º Tenho um campo texto onde vai ser digitado um numero e tem que ser multiplicado em todas as  com o id qtd_planejada.
Será de grande ajuda to perdido nisso.

```
<label for="qtd_planejada" class="col-md-2 control-label">Quantidade planejada:</label>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <form:input path='qtd_planejada' type='text' class="form-control" />
</div>
<form:errors path='qtd_planejada' />

<table id="estruturaTabela" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Item </th>
            <th> Descrição </th>
            <th> Quantidade Base </th>
            <th> Quantidade Planejada </th>
            <th> Disponivel </th>
            <th> Nome da UM </th>
            <th> Depósito </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="body">
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $('select[id=produto]').change(function() {
        var itemCode = $(this).val();
        var tbody;
        var tr;
        var tr = document.createElement('TR');
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/producao/estruturaProduto/' + itemCode,
            success: function(retorno) {
                console.log(retorno);
                if (retorno.length > 0) {
                    //TABLE ROWS
                    tbody = $('#body');
                    for (var i = 0; i < retorno.length; i++) {
                        tr = $('<tr/>').appendTo(tbody);
                        tr.append('<td id="itemcode">' + retorno[i].itemcode + '</td>');
                        tr.append('<td id="itemname">' + retorno[i].itemname + '</td>');
                        tr.append('<td id="qtd_base">' + retorno[i].qtd_base + '</td>');
                        tr.append('<td id="planejada">' + retorno[i].qtd_base + '</td>');
                        tr.append('<td id="disponivel">' + retorno[i].disponivel + '</td>');
                        tr.append('<td id="nomeUM">' + retorno[i].nomeum + '</td>');
                        tr.append('<td id="deposito">' + retorno[i].deposito + '</td>');
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: só não compreendi sobre o campo qtd_planejada, aonde está no código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, para limpar coloque este código:

```
$('select[id=produto]').change(function () {
   $('#estruturaTabela tbody').html('') // assim ele limpa o conteúdo da tbody
......
......
});
```

Comment: brigado meu velho era isso, tinha esquecido de por o campo qtd_planejada, para multiplicar o pelas tds eu teria que fazer outra função?

Comment: sim tem que ser em função separada, pois ela é acionada assim que um determinado número é inserido no campo e não quando a tabela é montada.

Comment: acho q o evento onblur me ajuda com isso, porém para eu calcular pelo campo q foi inserido pelo javascript n to visualizando isso..